# Swap level-one from index with column level (Pandas Multiindex Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindexed pandas.Dataframe which is something like this:

```
          BAZ    PAL
Foo  Bar          
124   1    A     B
      2    C     D
134   1    E     F
      2    G     H
```

I need to swap level-one from index with columns in appropriate way. I need to end up with something like this:

```
         124 134
Coo Bar
BAZ 1    A   E
    2    C   G
PAL 1    B   F
    2    D   H
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to unstack your existing index level `Foo`, stack your desired column 'Coo', and then rearrange the index levels.  After swapping your index levels, you probably want to sort it. As a final touch, you may want to drop the column name of all the values (`val`).

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'Foo': [124, 124, 134, 134] * 2, 
                    'Bar': [1, 2, 1, 2] * 2, 
                    'Coo': ['BAZ'] * 4 + ['PAL'] * 4, 
                    'val': list('ACEGBDFH')})
      .set_index(['Foo', 'Bar', 'Coo'])
      .unstack('Coo'))

>>> df
        val    
Coo     BAZ PAL
Foo Bar        
124 1     A   B
    2     C   D
134 1     E   F
    2     G   H

df = df.unstack('Foo').stack('Coo')
df.index = df.index.swaplevel(0, 1)

>>> df
        val    
Foo     124 134
Coo Bar        
BAZ 1     A   E
PAL 1     B   F
BAZ 2     C   G
PAL 2     D   H

df.sort_index(inplace=True)

>>> df
        val    
Foo     124 134
Coo Bar        
BAZ 1     A   E
    2     C   G
PAL 1     B   F
    2     D   H

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()

>>> df
Foo     124 134
Coo Bar        
BAZ 1     A   E
    2     C   G
PAL 1     B   F
    2     D   H
```